# Hibernate-Enver Duplicate event listener found

Tags: apache-karaf, hibernate-envers

`Hibernate-core 5.10.2` and `Hibernate-envers-5.10.2` with `persistance.xml`
if i add `hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners` to be `true` I got:

```
org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistrationException: Duplicate event listener found
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.listenerShouldGetAdded(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.appendListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.appendListeners(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerRegistryImpl.appendListeners(EventListenerRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversIntegrator.integrate(EnversIntegrator.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
```

If I set flag to be false, above exception does not appears but No insertion Query fired for _AUD tables. 
I am using Karaf 4.0.7 with feature installed as:

```
<feature version="5.2.10.Final" >hibernate-orm</feature>
<feature version="5.2.10.Final" >hibernate-envers</feature>
```

Can anyone help me out what I am Missing??

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved. Listeners needs to be register , SO i added :

```
    EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService( EventListenerRegistry.class );     
listenerRegistry.appendListeners( EventType.POST_UPDATE, new EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl( enversService ) );
    listenerRegistry.appendListeners( EventType.POST_INSERT, new EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl( enversService ) );
    listenerRegistry.appendListeners( EventType.PRE_UPDATE, new EnversPreUpdateEventListenerImpl( enversService ) );
```

Comment: These really should not require being registered manually.  The Envers integration with ORM automatically should be doing this.  In fact, we have several OSGi tests in our test suite and we never register them manually, so this must be something in your environment forcing you to do this.

Comment: Are you sure your Karaf instance isn't mixing multiple versions of Envers?

Comment: Yes only one version of hibernate is present.

Comment: @Naros may be you are correct but for me if i dnt registers these events No data get inserted in auditing tables